Late 90's Mecha Anime on Cartoon Network
Ok, so I saw a Mecha anime on Cartoon Network. 
There was a kid, he was taking a test of something with other kids up in space after leaving Earth. It was him and a girl, who really liked him.
There is a scene at the beginning where they were attacked or something.
The male character is on a believe a glass bridge or something and then his HAIR GLOWS... pretty sure it was blue.
It is NOT Gundam G. I know that for a fact.
The anime style is similar to Pilot Candidate and Gundam Wing.
I only saw a little bit of this anime... I think it was cancelled but not sure. It was a while ago. I think late 90s and early 2000s but don't quote me on that.

Is it possibly Eureka Seven? I never watched CN and the year it aired would've been 2005, but it sounds pretty similar to the other things described.

Could be Sym Bionic Titan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sym-Bionic_Titan
First episode date: September 17, 2010
Final episode date: April 9, 2011
It ran on Cartoon Network and there's some testing involved. The main character hair goes dark blue once the robot transforms and there is lot of blue involved in any case.



Second option is Megas XLR. Giant robot, blue. Jaime, one of the main characters is constantly wearing blue cap. That one aired from 2004-2005
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361201/
First episode here:



Another option I have is Vandread, but I am not certain that show ever aired on Cartoon Network. Yet another option is Firebreather, the movie which aired on Cartoon Network in 2010. That one doesn't have as many giant robots but it does have giant monsters!
